# If $x_n, y_n \ge 0$ and $x_{n+1}-x_n < y_n$ and $\sum_n y_n < \infty$, then $x_n$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Suppose $\{x_n\},\{y_n\}$ are non-negative sequences.
>   $x_{n+1}-x_n<y_n$ holds for all $n$. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}y_n$ is
>   convergent. Prove $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x_n$ exists.

From the assumption conditions, we can obtain:

- $\forall \varepsilon>0, x_{n+1}-x_n<y_n<\varepsilon $ holds for a
  sufficiently large $n$;
- $\exists M>0,x_{n+1}-x_1=\sum_{k=1}^n(x_{k+1}-x_k)<\sum_{k=1}^n y_k<M$.

But can we go on from here?

Comment: yes, a typo. sorry

Comment: Hint: Do you know about Cauchy sequences?

Comment: The $x_n$ are a Cauchy-sequence do you can use completeness of the real numbers

Comment: I edited the title a good bit so that it is much more descriptive for future readers. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: $\lim x_n$ exists if and only if $\liminf x_n = \limsup x_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Define $a_n,b_n$ as follows: $$0\leq a_n:=(x_{n+1}-x_n)^+=\max(x_{n+1}-x_n,0),$$ $$0\leq b_n:=(x_{n+1}-x_n)^-=-\min(x_{n+1}-x_n,0).$$ Letting $M=\sum_{k\geq 1}y_k$, one has $$x_{n+1}-x_n\leq (x_{n+1}-x_n)^+=a_n\leq y_n$$ $$\Rightarrow 0\leq \sum_{k=1}^n a_k\leq \sum_{k\geq 1}y_k=M.\qquad (1)$$ By definition, $$a_n-b_n=x_{n+1}-x_n,n\geq 1$$ $$\Rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^n(a_k-b_k)=x_{n+1}-x_1$$ $$\Rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^na_k-\sum_{k=1}^nb_k=x_{n+1}-x_1\qquad (2)$$ $$\Rightarrow 0\leq \sum_{k\geq 1}^nb_k=\sum_{k=1}^na_k-(x_{n+1}-x_1)$$$$\leq \sum_{k=1}^na_k+x_1\leq M+x_1~({\rm by~}(1))\qquad (3).$$ From (1) and (3), it follows that both $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^na_k~{\rm and~}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{k=1}^nb_k$$ exist. It follows from (2) that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_{n+1}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(x_1+\sum_{k=1}^na_k-\sum_{k=1}^nb_k)$$ exist. QED